# Does Youtube chromeless player API support High Quality playback?

Tags: api, video, youtube

... and if so how do I load high quality versions?

cheers

Comment: Have you ever found a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

It does not support HQ or HD playback yet.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the Youtube Chromeless player supports HQ, but you should never force HQ on users, as you don't know the speed or the preference of the users.

Answer (score 0):

"high quality" can be specified as a URL parameter: "&fmt=18"

"HD" is "&fmt=22".

Not sure what you mean by "chromeless player", but from the browser URL you can specify that the player start with no other window fluff by using the "watch_popup" action instead of "watch" - http://www.youtube.com/watch_popup?v=Yu_moia-oVI

apparently the "fmt" parameter doesn't work on the "watch_popup" page, but that's the only snag I've found.

does that help at all?